# How to wipe and reinstall Centos remotely?

Tags: ssh, centos, reinstall, wipe

Long story short, I removed the default python version Centos 6.8 comes with, and now Yum is broken.  At this point, it seems best to completely try again.

In light of this, how can I wipe the current machine and install a fresh Centos environment remotely?

Comment: Long story short, you can't. Your `ssh` session is part of that OS that is running on your server and you can't wipe it unless you wipe your session and connection to that server.

Comment: I don't entirely agree with @Jakuje, it may be possible, depending on how your system was partitioned, but it will almost certainly be extremely difficult, very specific to your current setup details, and beyond the scope of what can be reasonably described in an answer here.  Anyway, are you sure you can't get a IP-KVM or something attached to the system or some other out-of-band access?

Comment: In light of this, I've adjusted the question to relax the specifications, should that help.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. As SSH connects to the operating system. Basically once you wipe the OS, you lose connectivity.